# How can i display div element who contain rating in JSDF angular4

Tags: angular

This is my HTML File:

> ```
>  <div id="stars" style="font-size: 15px;" class="stars-outer">
>   <div class="stars-inner" [style.width]="setStarsRating(4)">
>    </div>
>
>   </div>
> ```

This is my ts file:

```
 var specialElementHandlers = {
 '#stars': function (element, renderer) {
     return true;
 } }; $('#cmd').click(function () {   
 doc.fromHTML($('#stars').html(), 15, 15, {
     'width': 170,
         'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
 });
 doc.save('sample-file.pdf'); });
```

Comment: first) why tag angular if youre using jquery? second) you dont have a `setStartRating()` function

Comment: I'm using jquery in angular4 and i have setStartRating in my Ts file

Comment: why? thats bulking the application for no reason

Comment: Just temporary  , have you any idea about my problem?